# How does Kotlin flow created with BroadcastChannel.asFlow() context preservation work?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Here is an example to illustrate my confusion:

```
fun main() = runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default + CoroutineName("Main")) {
    val broadcaster = BroadcastChannel<Int>(Channel.BUFFERED)
    val flow = withContext(CoroutineName("InitialFlowCreation")) {
        broadcaster.asFlow()
            .map {
                println("first mapping in context: $coroutineContext")
                it * 10
            }
            .broadcastIn(CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default + CoroutineName("BroadcastIn")))
            .asFlow()
    }

    val updatedFlow = withContext(CoroutineName("UpdatedFlowCreation")) {
        flow.map {
            println("second mapping in context: $coroutineContext")
            it * 10
        }
            .flowOn(Dispatchers.Default + CoroutineName("FlowOn"))
    }

    launch(CoroutineName("Collector")) {
        updatedFlow.collect {
            println("Collecting $it in context: $coroutineContext")
        }
    }

    delay(1_000)

    launch(CoroutineName("OriginalBroadcast")) {
        for (i in 1..10) {
            broadcaster.send(i)
            println("Sent original broadcast from: $coroutineContext")
            delay(1_000)
        }
    }

    return@runBlocking
}
```

This produces the following output (truncated):

```
Sent original broadcast from: [CoroutineName(OriginalBroadcast), StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@3a14b06a, DefaultDispatcher]
first mapping in context: [CoroutineName(InitialFlowCreation), UndispatchedCoroutine{Completed}@40202c08, DefaultDispatcher]
second mapping in context: [CoroutineName(UpdatedFlowCreation), UndispatchedCoroutine{Completed}@6cf04ddc, DefaultDispatcher]
Collecting 100 in context: [CoroutineName(Collector), StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@6ac9d4b5, DefaultDispatcher]
```

The documentation states things in various places that causes me to be confused by this result.
In [Flow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow/index.html) we have "Use channelFlow if the collection and emission of a flow are to be separated into multiple coroutines. It encapsulates all the context preservation work and allows you to focus on your domain-specific problem, rather than invariant implementation details. It is possible to use any combination of coroutine builders from within channelFlow." I know I'm not actually using the `channelFlow` function but a `ChannelFlow` is being created internally when we call `broadcastIn` so the same principals should apply.

I thought the first invocation of `map` would be run in the `"OriginalBroadcast"` context and the second would either be run in the `"BroadcastIn"` context or the `"Collector"` context but instead they are both run in the context where they are called. I don't understand why this is happening, shouldn't the context of `map` be where it is collected in order to be broadcast or the context where it is finally collected, not the context where map is called? Also the call to `flowOn` has no effect. What context preservation work is being encapsulated here?

Also am I correct that in a chain of `flow.broadcastIn(...).asFlow().map{...}.broadcastIn(...).asFlow()` the two `BroadcastChannel`s created will not be fused? Trying to make sure I'm not missing something.

I guess what I'm really looking for is inclusive documentation of in what situation `Channel`s are fused, how they are fused, and what context the operators that are called between `ChannelFlow` operators will run in.

Comment: Did you end up using `channelFlow`?

Answer (score 1):

The context preservation only applies to operations on flows, e.g. the code in `flow { ... }` builder works in the same context that calls `collect()`. The context is not preserved when operating via channels by the very nature of channels. Channels are communication primitives that are designed for communication *between* different coroutines.

It means that when you call `broadcaster.send` in one coroutine it will be received in another coroutine, in a coroutine that collects from the corresponding flow.

The documentation on `channelFlow` simply means that you don't have to worry about context preservation violation, which is non-trivial to ensure if you were to write such a primitive yourself.

Comment: I did some more experimenting and noticed that when I got rid of `runBlocking` and `withContext` it behaves exactly as I would have expected. So it seems in my example when an operator is added to a flow from a coroutine, that operator will execute in that coroutine, but if it isn't, it will execute in the coroutine used for `broadcastIn` / `flowOn` / `collect` as expected. It seems error prone to change the execution context of `Flow` operators depending on if the operator was added to the flow in a coroutine / suspend function or not. I also can't find any documentation on this behavior.

Comment: Can you, please, submit your example code to https://github.com/kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues

Comment: Yep. https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1899